# Why does Auto Layout break down when bringing app from background to foreground?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm working an iOS movie app which has a home screen and a "Select Genres" screen.

When tapping a button on the home screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9M4D.png), it sends the user to the Select Genres screen (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeOrk.jpg).

All is well and good so far.

However, if I go back to the home screen, minimize the app, open it again and once again tap the same button, the Auto Layout of the Select Genres screen gets messed up (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ew5jC.jpg).

As you can see:

- The "Back Home" button mixes with the time
- The main title gets pushed up
- The bottom button gets moved down to the point where it touches the safe area

It basically pushes the content on the top up (where the navigation bar would be) and also ignores the constraint of the button on the bottom and pushes it to touch the Safe Area.

By the way, I'm using both a navigation bar and a tab bar, which I hide for the Select Genres screen. It looks like this could be the source of the problem.

I set up Auto Layout constraints on the Select Genres screen, which work well as long as the app doesn't get sent to the background and then brought to the foreground.

I've tried playing around with the Simulated Metrics of Top Bar and Bottom Bar in Storyboard, but the same problem keeps happening.

Do you have any idea what could be happening here?

Thank you!

Comment: Watch the Xcode console. Any relevant messages? Also, when the messed-up state occurs, switch to the Xcode View Debugger. Any exclamation marks? If you can't learn anything that way, you will have to describe your interface for us (and perhaps your view controller hierarchy) in much more detail.

Comment: Thanks for posting the screen shots. It looks to me like in the second scene you are trying to use a navigation bar without being in a UINavigationController interface. That could be your problem. The autolayout for such a navigation bar is very tricky. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks for answering, matt! So I went to check the messages and I'm getting "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for HomeViewController". I'm reading up on causes for this and there can be several: animations while transitioning, presenting a VC twice, among others. On the other hand, here's the setup of the VCs: https://imgur.com/a/zlq6dn8. A Nav Bar is the main, followed by a nav and then the VCs. In theory, the nav should contain both the Home and Select Genres VCs, right? Looking forward to your thoughts!